# Rails 4 JavaScript / JQuery render multiple partial through edit controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get multiple partials on the same index view with the same edit controller action.

Basically i have a list of both ID's and of shipping quantity's i would like the user to enter. The partials have both of the form inputs with an update button. However, when i try do use the partials as follows no matter which "Edit" link i click both partials show up regardless of which js ID i have set for the table column.

My edit action in controller:

```
def edit
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
    end
 end
```

Part of my index view:

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <td id="packlist"><%= invoice.readpacklistid %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_invoice_path(invoice), :remote => true %></td>
  <td id="shipqty"><%= invoice.shippedqty %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_invoice_path(invoice), :remote => true %></td>
<% end %>
```

My edit.js.erb contains:

```
$('#shipqty').append( "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'shippedqty', :locals => {'invoice' => @invoice}) ) %>");
$("#packlist").append( "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'packlist', :locals => {'invoice' => @invoice}) ) %>");
```

_shippedqty.html.erb partials contains:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :shippedqty %>
  <%= f.select :shippedqty, options_for_invoices(@invoice.customerorderid) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", invoices_path %>
<% end %>
```

_packlist.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :packlistid %>
  <%= f.select :packlistid, options_for_packlistid(@invoice.customerorderid, @invoice.shippedqty), :selected => :packlistid %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I would like both of these partials to show up on the same page but show up one at a time when clicked on their desired link. I just find it much more beneficial to the user than having to click a link to edit these all at once.

This is using Rails 4.1.8 and Ruby 2.1.0p0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this which makes it easy.

Invoices.helper

```
def options_for_shippedqty(customerid)
  Shipperline.getshippqty(customerid)
end

#Used to get all the packlistid for a invoice record for drop down select

def options_for_packlistid(customerid, shipqty)
 Shipperline.packlist(customerid, shipqty)
end
```

Then in my view

```
<%= form_for invoice do |f| %>
   <% @packlistFromList = options_for_packlistid(invoice.customerID,     invoice.shippedqty).first %>
 <% if @packlistFromList.nil? %>
   <td id="putcolor"><%= f.text_field :packlistid %><%= f.submit "Update  Packlist", { :class => "btn btn-primary" } %>
 <% else %>
   <td id="putcolor"><%= f.select :packlistid, options_for_packlistid(invoice.customerID, invoice.shippedqty) %><%= f.submit  "Update Packlist", { :class => "btn btn-primary"} %></td>
 <% end %>
  <% @shipQty = options_for_shippedqty(invoice.customerID).first %>
 <% if @shipQty.nil? %>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= f.text_field :shippedqty %><%= f.submit "Update Shipping QTY", { :class => "btn btn-primary" } %>
 <% else %>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= f.select :shippedqty, options_for_shippedqty(invoice.customerID) %><%= f.submit "Update Shipping QTY", { :class => "btn btn-primary"} %></td>
 <% end %>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= invoice.adder %></td>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= invoice.adderprice %></td>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= invoice.difference %></td>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= f.text_area :comments %><%= f.submit "Add Comment",  { :class => "btn btn-primary"} %></td>
  <td id="putcolor"><%= f.check_box :completed %><%= f.submit "Submit   Completion", { :class => "btn btn-primary"} %></td>
  <td class="hidden"><%= invoice.orgShippedQty %></td>
  <td class="hidden"><%= invoice.getPrecMetalAmount %></td>
  <td class="hidden"><%= invoice.orgPackList %>
  <td class="hidden"><%= invoice.invoiceNum %>
 </tr>
</tbody>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I porpouse you, render Partial from AJAX, I explain myself:

- When a user click on edit, you have to make a ajax call to an action
  edit that correspond.
- This actions should return a html code (the form).
- Append this html code where you want in success param of AJAX. (use
  $jquery.html)
- Delete de form after use it.

Or

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <td id="'packlist'+@invoice.id"><%= invoice.readpacklistid %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_invoice_path(invoice), :remote => true %></td>
  <td id="'shipqty'+@invoice.id"><%= invoice.shippedqty %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_invoice_path(invoice), :remote => true %></td>
<% end %>
```

and

```
$('#shipqty+@invoice.id').append( "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'shippedqty', :locals => {'invoice' => @invoice}) ) %>");
$("#packlist+@invoice.id").append( "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'packlist', :locals => {'invoice' => @invoice}) ) %>");
```

Comment: Please put the reason of downVote

Comment: Could you give an example please? 

Do you mean just use $('#shipqty').html instead of .append?

I just tried both .html for edit.js.erb but it still shows both partials on each "edit" link clicked. I compiled assets just to be sure.

Comment: The problem occurs because you're sharing id's

Comment: If you use append or something else all html, will be attached at all  $('#shipqty'), I was porpousing another way to do the same

Comment: I am sorry but I think I am miss understanding. Both columns in my index view have seperate id's. One column has a shipqty id and the other has a packlist id.

Do you mean putting ids in with the link_to code?

Comment: You're creating multiple <td id='packlist'>, one for each invoice, it isn't?. The problem occurs when you appen on an id of html that would be unique

Comment: Each invoice record is going to have a unique id. For id is my primary key. Also, yes, each td would have an id of 'packlist' or 'shippedqty' for that column belonging to each record.

However, when i click the edit button on various records in my view i can see that the rails console is rendering correctly for each record of invoice.

Comment: When i try that the rails console tries to load it but the partial does not show up on the index page. I compiled my assets again as well.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more, I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your `edit.js.erb` file you are rendering both file that is why your getting both from at the same time.
Even you are not able to figure out in your edit action which link was clicked as you are not sending anything to segregate both links.

you need to send some identifier in params whenever a user click on any of these links and then in edit.js.erb use if/else based on these params condition, to figure out which file needs to render.